# How to get the role for current user with Spring Security

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-security, waffle

I'm trying to fetch all the roles for the current user who has been authenticated and show them in a JSP page.

I notice that there are some built-in expressions listed here: http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/el-access.html but I don't see any that would list all the roles.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use `SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getAuthorities()` to obtain a collection of the currently logged in user's roles.